# MVC 3 - Do some task at interval time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an web app with ASP.NET MVC3. 
The requirement is: At some time interval (0:00AM or 10:00pm), the app must automatically do some task such as: Change order status in DB, send notify email to customer, clear temp folder....

I'm thinking of using a thread in Global.aspx, let it run and sleep for 24 hours, but I don't think that is a good resolution.

@Thank to patryk-wiek comment, I find a solution with " Task Scheduler MVC" keywork here.
https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler

Is that a good solution or not? I think writing a window service is a bit overkill for me?

Comment: You can use any kind of job/task scheduling system, outside the application (Windows Task Scheduler) or inside, e.g. [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Take a look at the [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class. This allows you to hook up a callback when the timer elapses.

Comment: Be careful, IIS will kill your Application Pool process at any time and without warning, so your scheduled task might never run. I recommend an out-of-process trigger that will fire-up your IIS web application and execute the desired code.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it in your web application as you may not be in control of when the host process times out and goes!

Create a windows service to perform these tasks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use RX for the same by creating a window service for the same.. as i have attached one sample code below which would suscibe first and will do the operation in regular interval of 2 minutes.:-

```
 Observable.Generate(
                true,
                _ => true,
                i =>
                {
                   ////your code...

                    return i;
                },
                i => i,
                _ => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)).Subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it inside your web app, becasue the AppPool can be terminated at any time. There are ways how to prevent this, but it's not very clean solution.

Use windows scheduler, WCF service or some workflow solution for log running tasks.